# How to convert a 10 bit grayscale image to 8 bit image?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, imagej

I am trying to convert a a 10 bit grayscale image to 8 bit (using python). But I am not able to find a solution yet. The problem with 10 bit image is that I cannot view it in windows, it is showing blank image. Though the image is viewable with ImageJ tool. How can this be done?

The image is in .PNG format and the output is also expected to be in same format. The image is taken from camera and stored in local.

**UPDATE:** I tried the below code, now I am able to view the image but the image is different from original colors.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("sample.png")

im = im.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = im.split()
r = r.point(lambda i: i * 64)
b = b.point(lambda i: i * 64)
g = g.point(lambda i: i * 64)
out = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))
out.show()
```

I also tried the convert(L) method in PIL, it gave better result but still missing the original colors of image.

Comment: File ? Which format ? From camera ? Note that Windows is able to display 16 bpp TIFFs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Multiply each pixel by 64, and save the result as Tiff.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The image is in PNG format and the output is also expected to be in same format. The image is taken from camera and stored in local.

Comment: Then if possible convert 16 to 8 in memory before saving, or use the same library that you use for saving, to read-convert (in memory)-write.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the suggestion!! But in my case, I'm getting the images from other source so I cannot handle that.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks for the suggestion!! I tried the below `code`
**import Image
im = Image.open('1_tree.png')
im = im.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = im.split()
r = r.point(lambda i: i * 64)
b = b.point(lambda i: i * 64)
g = g.point(lambda i: i * 64)
out = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))
out.show()**


Now, I am able to view the image but it is not showing the original colors that the image had earlier (as seen with ImageJ tool). Could you please guide me What I am missing here?

Comment: My guess is that now you are seeing the original colors, and ImageJ applies some "linear stretching". Is it 10 bit grayscale or RGB? In case you want an answer, find a way to post the original image (10 bits is not supported by SO). Also post the output of ImageJ tool.

Comment: It is 10 bit grayscale. I cannot share the images though.